# Is Java String really immutable?

Tags: java

In String source it looks like the hash code value (private int hashCode) is set only if the method public int hashCode() was called at least once. That means a different state. But will the hashCode be set in the following example:

```
String s = "ABC"; ?
```

Will

```
String s = "ABC"; 
s.hashCode();
```

help with subsequent comparisons performance?

Comment: [Wikipedia describes this situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 12):

Immutable means that, from an outside perspective, the value of the object cannot be changed.

If `hashCode` is being cached, the internal state of the object may be different after the first `hashCode` call.  But that call is read-only, and you can't change the value of the object as it appears to the outside world.

In other words, it's still the same string.

Comment: From wikipedia: "immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: Sigh. From the very same Wikipedia page: *"In some cases, an object is considered immutable even if some internally used attributes change but the object's state appears to be unchanging from an external point of view. For example, an object that uses memoization to cache the results of expensive computations could still be considered an immutable object."* The caching of the `hash` value is classic memoization.

Comment: Sigh. Performance is observable from the external point of view.

Comment: @Alex - SIGH ... but it is not an observable change in the object's STATE,

Comment: Sigh. If it walks like an immutable object, and quacks like an immutable object, it's an immutable object. Performance has nothing to do with immutability.

Answer (score 4):

**Technically** the string has changed. Some internal field is altered the first time you call `hashCode()`.

But for all **practical** reasons the string is immutable. The value of the hash code doesn't change due to a call to `hashCode()`, it simply isn't calculated until the first call. To any consumer of a string, the string is immutable. And that's what matters.

Answer (score 3):

As also stated by Robert Harvey and Greg, for all practical purposes, **String object is immutable** (it might be possible to change the contents with reflection but that is a hack).

Calling `hashCode()` immediately after construction **might help with performance IN THEORY**. However, for all practical purposes, this is **premature optimization**.

Comment: In fact, calling hashCode after construction would more likely to have negative effect on performance. The first time .hashCode() is called, the private field will be filled anyway; and you might actually benefit from not having to calculate the hashCode at all.

Comment: In fact in this specific case the optimization is very far from premature. That is a huge 12 years old application. Unfortunately known to work not fast enough. One and the same strings are compared millions and millions of times (I would use integers myself, but this is life). The second of compared strings comes from far away with a transaction and you bet it has no hasCode inside.

Comment: It is still premature - if this string is compared millions and millions of times, it does not matter if the first comparison was a bit slower than all the other (millions and millions - 1). The fact that first comparison was a bit slower is negligible.

Comment: You assume that after first comparison the hashCode is set? Not so.

Comment: By "comparison" I meant calling hashCode(), not calling equals(). http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#1041

Answer (score 2):

> But will the hashCode be set in the following example?

No.

> Will [calling hashCode] help with subsequent comparisons performance?

Assuming that you mean subsequent calls to `String.equals(Object)`, the answer is "No".  The `equals` method does not use a String's `hash` value, whether or not it has previously been calculated.

If you are referring to calls to `String.hashCode()`, the answer is "Probably Not".  At most you are getting a one-time calculation to happen sooner rather than later.  The `hashCode` method still needs to test if `hash` is zero on every call.

**EDIT**

I think it is clear that different JVM vendors implement String.equals differently.  For example, the IBM version cited by @Alex uses the cached hashcode, but the version in Sun's JDK 1.6 does not.

From this we conclude that any attempt to call `String.hashCode()` in order to "optimize" `String.equals` is going to have results that depend on the JVM.  Furthermore, for the particular IBM JVM that @Alex is using, it looks like it *could* be beneficial ... provided that you've done it for both strings.

But I still think this is a bad idea ... unless you've got clear evidence from profiling that `String.equals()` is a significant bottleneck.

Comment: It may be the case that this behavior is not defined by Java standards. But the implementation of String I work with USES the hash value if both strings have it set.

Comment: @Alex - the implementation of String in OpenJDK 1.6 does not.  What version are you using?

Comment: I am using IBM version from RAD

Comment: /*
 * Licensed Materials - Property of IBM,
 *     Copyright IBM Corp. 1998, 2007  All Rights Reserved
 */

Comment: public boolean equals (Object object) {
    if (object == this) return true;
    if (object instanceof String) {
    String s = (String)object;
    if (count != s.count ||
     (hashCode != s.hashCode && hashCode != 0 && s.hashCode != 0))
                                return false;
    return regionMatches(0, s, 0, count);
    }
return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Nobody calls it so it isn't called.
2. No. How could calling a method an extra time make anything faster?

Comment: questioner could mean 'faster during subsequent calls, at the expense of setup speed'.

Comment: He *does* mean that. But he is still slowing down his overall program. So what's the difference?

Comment: @EJP You're assuming his program is linear. If there was a significant difference in subsequent calls (a big 'if'), then the method call could first be made when something else is the bottleneck, e.g. while waiting for disk access. Then if hashCode is called later, in a CPU intensive area of code, an overall improvement could be gained. Theoretically.

Comment: @Grundlefleck I do not understand. Calling a method twice can't be faster than calling it once.

Comment: @EJP No it can't, but making the slower call at one point in your program so that it's faster at another point might give a *net* reduction in time. It's fairly obtuse, but if you had a million objects in memory, which were all going to have hashCode called on them in a loop, pre-populating their hashCode while your program is waiting for a file to load, could speed up the loop. Unlikely, but possible :)

Comment: @Grundlefleck Fair enough but what does that have to do with 'linear'?

Comment: @EJP Read 'linear' as 'single threaded', perhaps a poor choice of words in hindsight. In my example there would need to be some kind of concurrency for it to make sense at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is the actual String.hashCode() implementation:

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;    // hash is a field in String
if (h == 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;
    int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

So:

1. Strings are immutable, you can not change it's value. You can only create a new String.
2. String hashcode gets calculated on first use of String.hashCode(). Later invocations return precalculayed value:
3. **YES, it will be faster.** If you call .hashCode() then subsequent comparisons will be faster for a tiny amount of time of one-time calculating hachcode. The question is if this is substantial. Do your own benchmark.

Comment: See my answer. How can calling a method an extra time possibly be faster?

Comment: Total time will obviously be the same, but subsequent comparisons will be marginally faster (for the one time calc of hashcode, as I wrote). This is what original poster was asking.